How to pass two different data in two different inputs referring to the same field
how to pass two different data in two different inputs referring to the same field in vue 3 and primevue components?
I have column InputDate and i want to filter data from to but don't know how? Can someone explain if it possbile?
Below I put my vue3 code:
Thats my filters:
  const filters = ref({
    //InputDate: { value: '', matchMode: FilterMatchMode.GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO },
    InputDate: {
        from: { value: '', matchMode: FilterMatchMode.GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO },
        to: { value: '', matchMode: FilterMatchMode.LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO }
    },
  });

And here is my template:
<InputText class="filter-input" type="date" v-model="filters['InputDate'].from.value" />
<InputText class="filter-input" type="date" v-model="filters['InputDate'].to.value"/>

And it doesn't work if i would refer to InputDate without from or to it works.
I was looking on internet but not found solution

Please, provide a way to reproduce. There's no such problem in general. As long as filters['InputDate'].from.value path exists, it works. It doesn't matter for InputText components if it's "same" field

I mean there is columun InputDate and i want to filter the date by using this name so InputDate.from or InputDate.to doesn't match with path so i cant filter date from to becouse the correct path is InputDate. When both inputs models are InputDate of course it changes value in both inputs.
